# ¿Diferencia entre 0 y NULL?

Tags: null, ram

Últimamente me estoy dedicando a cambiar la RAM de los programas para ver como reaccionan, y esto me ha sacado una duda

¿Hay alguna diferencia entre una variable con el valor `0` y una con el valor `NULL`?

En teoría no, dado que un `int` con valor `0` tiene el valor `0x00` en RAM, pero el valor `NULL` también en `0x00`

¿Podría alguien resolver mi duda?

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Comment: ***¿Hay alguna diferencia entre una variable con el valor 0 y una con el valor NULL?*** Va a depender del lenguaje y del CPU. Por ejemplo, en C, `Null` es una constante cuyo valor es cero, pero también puede ser un puntero que apunta a la nada. En SQL, `Null` se refiere a la ausencia de datos. En C# `Null` significa que no hay un objeto. Entonces, aunque su valor pueda ser igual, la interpretación de cada lenguaje será diferente, no pudiendo sustituir uno por el otro. Saludos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He esatdo investigando tu pregunta ya que me ha parecido muy interesante.
He encontrado lo siguiente buscando por nuestra comunidad de Stackoverflow en inglés.
Esto ocurre porque **el valor NULL en ram se representa como 0**, entonces el valor 0 y el valor NULL siempre se representa como 0x00, te dejo por **[aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128024/where-is-null-in-memory)** el enlace donde he encontrado al información

Además te dejo una imagen muy descriptiva entre la **diferencia** de **NULL** y el valor **0**.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda
¡Un saludo!

Comment: El enlace me lleva a la imagen adjunta :(

Comment: Buenas, perdón por la confusión con el enlace, ya esta arreglado ¡gracias por avisar!

Comment: :) Gracias por el link